# How to download data from the Google Calendar API to R

Tags: r, api, google-calendar-api

I have been trying to get the google calendar API to work off and on for years and can't figure it out. I have an API key through google, but I have not found documentation of how to successfully use it in R. I have tried using the googleAuthR and gcalendar libraries. If someone has sample code that they can provide, I would be so greatful. I just need code to access the data through API and convert the data to a data frame to work with the data in R.

Comment: Have you tried this?
https://github.com/andrie/gcalendr/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I have! This seemed like the perfect solution, but I couldn't get the authentification to work and even if I did, it did not seem like there were any functions in the gcalendr R package to download data from google calendar. The package seemed more tailored to adding events to an existing google calendar.

Comment: I was not even able to authenticate using gcalendar

Comment: https://rdrr.io/github/benjcunningham/googlecalendar/
I keep trying use this one. The authentication is hard, you must create a project in Google Console and include calendar API. You will have a key and a secret to authenticate in R. I was able to query calendars and events. But I had trouble when the calendar have many events and I could find a way to filter by dates. I suggest you to try this googlecalendar package. Hope that may help. Regards!